# How to selectively (un)subscribe IMAP folders in 10.9 Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, macos

I cannot find a way to selectively subscribe to IMAP folders in Mail.app in 10.9

Is there a way? Am I missing something there? It seems the IMAP implementation in Mail.app is still quite buggy and plays especially bad with dovecot IMAP servers.

Comment: It's not just dovecot, it's Zimbra as well (at least). I also don't appear to be able to subscribe/unsubscribe from iCloud IMAP folders either (list is empty).

Answer (score 2):

In theory: Control+click an IMAP folder in Mail, and select Get Account Info from the context menu. In the resulting dialog, select the Subscription List tab. Then subscribe and unsubscribe as desired.

In practice, I'm not sure whether that actually works; I can't test it on my particular system.